# Rails Routing Error uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following error when trying to log out from an authentication gem I have just install.

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/sign_out

Routing Error
uninitialized constant UsersController
```

I dont have a users_controller.rb file. 
I do have a user.rb Model.

This is the path/url i am trying to reach:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
```

Any idea?

Comment: What authentication gem do you use? Is it `devise`?

Comment: Ivan, it is devise. 

Routes.rb

  resources :credits
  resources :users


  devise_for :users

  resources :statuses

  root to: 'statuses#index'

Comment: Have you tried doing a text search throughout your app for `UsersController`?

Comment: No results. Do I need to have a Users Controller in order to perform those actions?

Comment: Post your full stacktrace

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that `devise_for :users` is overshadowed by `resources :users`

Rails complains about UsersController, because it thinks that you are trying to reach `users#show` (if you use GET request) and `users#destroy` (if you use DELETE)

[image]

You should either create UsersController or remove `resources :users` from your routes. And if you decide to create UserController, move `resources :users` under `devise_for :users`. Devise routes would take precedence that way.

Are you sure that you need `resources :users`?